# How do online advertisers load their ads through <script>, javascript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ads

Okay so I have googled a lot and have not found how they do it.

Examples 1:
**Here is a sample Code of PropellerAdsMedia:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.oclaserver.com/apu.php?zoneid='0000'"></script>
```

Example 2:
**Yllix Ad Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ylx-4.com/layer.php?section=General&pub='00000'&ga=g&fp"></script>
```

I want to do something similar but what i want to do is  use javascript to load 
these ad codes.

I have multiple website and also have multiple Advertisers. I want to echo random ad code on my website.

**AM I DOING SOMETHING WRONG?**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ad Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>  
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/ad.php?id=yllix"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/ad.php?id=googleads"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/ad.php?id=clicksor"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

**And MY PHP As per the first answer:**

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

switch ($id) {

 case "yllix":
 echo 'document.write(\'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ylx-1.com/bnr.php?section=General&pub=686929&format=300x250&ga=g"></script>
                        <noscript>
                        <a href="https://yllix.com/publishers/686929" target="_blank"><img src="https://yllix.com/banners/aff/pub/300x250.jpg" border="0" /></a></noscript>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ylx-4.com/layer.php?section=General&pub=686929&ga=g&show=1&fp"></script>\');';


 break;
 case "googleads":

      //google Ad Code Echo
    echo    'document.write(\'<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

                        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                             style="display:block"
                             data-ad-client="ca-pub-3293789816750173"
                             data-ad-slot="6844557963"
                             data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
                        <script>
                        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                        </script>\');';

 break;
 case "clicksor":
     //Clicksor Code Echo
         echo "document.write(\"<script type='text/javascript'> 
                        clicksor_adhere_opt='left'; 

                        clicksor_default_url = '';
                        clicksor_banner_border = '#99CC33'; 
                        clicksor_banner_ad_bg = '#FFFFFF';
                        clicksor_banner_link_color = '#000000'; 
                        clicksor_banner_text_color = '#666666';
                        clicksor_layer_border_color = '';
                        clicksor_layer_ad_bg = ''; 
                        clicksor_layer_ad_link_color = '';
                        clicksor_layer_ad_text_color = ''; 
                        clicksor_text_link_bg = '';
                        clicksor_text_link_color = ''; 
                        clicksor_enable_text_link = false;

                        clicksor_banner_text_banner = true;
                        clicksor_banner_image_banner = true; 
                        clicksor_enable_layer_pop = false;
                        clicksor_enable_pop = true;
                        </script>
                    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://b.clicksor.net/show.php?nid=1&amp;pid=380499&amp;adtype=1&amp;sid=638894'></script>\");";

 break;
    default:
        echo "document.write('Sorry')";
        break;
}
?>
```

Nothing is loaded from the script tags from the page.

Comment: Your `switch` syntax is wrong. It should be `switch ($id)`

Comment: The URL parameter should be `?ad=googleads`, without a `?` after `=`

Comment: @Hallur Since he's just loading a real adserver's script, he's letting them do the ad tailoring.

Comment: Okay Corrected some typos! I knew it would be downvoted. The Code given here is just an example code. So ignore that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page loaded with a `<script>` tag must be a plain Javascript script, not HTML. So you can't just echo a `<script>` tag, you have to echo a Javascript script that ads the script to the page. It can do this using `document.write()` (this is one of the few places where this function is still useful).

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

switch ($id) {
 case "yllix":

 //What to write here so that My <script> tag could load this echo by replacing itself like most ad code does?

 echo 'document.write(\'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ylx-4.com/layer.php?section=General&pub=&apos;000&apos;&ga=g&fp"></script>\');';
 break;
 case "googleads":

      //google Ad Code Echo

 break;
 case "PropellerAdsMedia":

     //PropellerAdsMedia Code Echo

 break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Just what i was looking for. This will help me manage my advertisements code in one single page instead of going through all the codes in many different websites!

Comment: Although not all scripts are echoed.

Comment: I tried adding all codes but am i missing something? the `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/myadloader.php?ad=yllix"></script>` is loaded but not the but document.write is not echoed from the php. Only the above ad code it works rest it does not.

Comment: NVM I fixed it by removing the spaces within the `document.write()` Thanks again. Should have mentioned that spaces can make them fail!

Comment: The problem wasn't spaces, it was the single quotes embedded in the ad URL. I replaced them with `&apos;` entities, now it works.

Comment: no actually I have written the code above which i used as example to test your answer. You can check yourself that it did not work. The ' ' was a typo residual i left from my original code. its not `&apos;`. For some reason the ads did not load when they were in formatted order. But by removing spaces it did work. Test it yourself to see the affect. The "formatted ad" code php is above in the question i had edited. Just remove spaces in the ad codes inside `document.write` to make it work.

Comment: Post your working code as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: I think you mean you removed the *newlines*. That makes sense, since newlines aren't allowed in Javascript string literals. If you want to split a string across multiple lines you can write `'string part 1' + <newline> + 'string part 2'` (where `<newline>` represents a line break).